# WCF security with Domain Groups

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a WCF service which I would like to secure with windows domain groups.  I do not want to include the PrincipalPermission attibute in the code!

I would like to call the services from a web application using the application pool identity.  This identity would be checked to ensure that it is a member of the domain group securing the WCF service.  All of this would be defined in config.  This seems like a really neat solution, except ..... defining the domain group as securing the WCF service does not seem possible.  Anyone got any ideas how I might do this.

I am using netTCPBinding (or named pipes but prefer the netTCP) and hosting the service in IIS within windows 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding , you want to use imperative checking than declarative checking at design time.

If thats the case you can replace the declaration with an imperative checing in the method body like

```
 PrincipalPermission checkPerminssions = new PrincipalPermission(
                                null, @"DomainName\WindowsGroup");


checkPerminssions .Demand();
```

You can also use IsInRole method using IPrincipal Interface.

However you can find more information at [Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649821.aspx)

I would love to know why you want to do that.

Hope this helps.